# How do i display the genres of a particular movie from tmdb api

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the details of the the movie using tmdb api so fall everything was good until i tried to display all the genres of that movie

```
const tmdb_api_url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/" + 127332 + "?api_key=API-KEY";

async function getDetails() {
  const response = await fetch (tmdb_api_url);
  const data = await response.json();
  const { name, first_air_date, vote_average, number_of_seasons, episode_run_time, genres, overview, origin_country} = data;

  document.getElementById('title').textContent = name;
  document.getElementById('first_air_date').textContent = first_air_date;
  document.getElementById('vote_average').textContent = vote_average;
  document.getElementById('number_of_seasons').textContent = number_of_seasons + " Season" + (number_of_seasons == 1 ? "" : "s ");
  document.getElementById('run_time').textContent = episode_run_time;
  document.getElementById('overview').textContent = overview;
  document.getElementById('origin_country').textContent = origin_country;
  var g = "";
  for (i in genres) {
    g += genres[i].name;
  }
  document.getElementById('genres').textContent = genres[i].name;
}

getDetails();
```

This is what i tried but its only showing one genre

And can anyone help me simplify the code what i tried

Comment: I was only able to achieve this by adding a few lines from SO and what made sense to me otherwise i am just a noob

Comment: can you show us what ```genres``` look like ?

Comment: @VersifiXion https://i.imgur.com/mcpr02R.png this is what i want but can only achieve this https://i.imgur.com/XLbPSMQ.png

Comment: and how the ```genres``` array or object look like ? can you do a ```console.log(genres)``` and show us ?

Comment: Remove the api key added to the fiddle. Provide/Added only what is the response you are getting from the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting only one genre because of this line `document.getElementById('genres').textContent = genres[i].name;`

This will always display the last genre.

Modify it as follows

```
var g = "";
for (i in genres) {
    g += genres[i].name + ", ";
}
document.getElementById('genres').textContent = g.substr(0, g.length - 1); // to remove last , added
```

**Update :** Adding each genre in there respective anchor tag

```
let genreTags = "";

for(i in genres){
    genreTags+= `<a href="${genre_link}">${genres[i].name}</a>`; // Add genre link in the href
}

document.getElementById("genres").innerHTML = genreTags;
```

This is the jist of adding genres as anchor, but there are much better ways of doing it.

Comment: Hey @AbhishekGowda28 can you say me how can i add each genre in their respective anchor tag.

Comment: hey @AbhishekGowda28 its not working i even added the g which was not defined and took out the ${genre_link} since i still didnt work on that but it does not display anything

Comment: `genre_link` is just a name I gave. You need to pass in proper link of the genre. Since I don't completely know the API of TMDB, you need to get the links to the genre when the app loads and map/attach it here.